# Unable to get entity using named query on jasypt encrypted column

Tags: hibernate, jasypt

I have an Employee entity having ssn field encrypted using jasypt. Following is a mock definition:

```
@TypeDef(name = "encryptedString", typeClass = EncryptedStringType.class, parameters = {@Parameter(name = "encryptorRegisteredName",value = "strongHibernateStringEncryptor")})
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
@NamedQueries(value = {
    @NamedQuery(name = "employee.getEmployeeBySSN", query = "SELECT employee from Employee employee WHERE employee.ssn=:ssn"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "employee.getEmployeeByName", query = "SELECT employee from Employee employee WHERE employee.name=:name")
    })
public class Employee {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @Type(type = "encryptedString")
    private String ssn;
}
```

This entity contains two named queries for getting employees, one with name and other with ssn. SSN field is encrypted using jasypt. The code is a mock implementation hence I have used the following basic configuration:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SerialException, SQLException {

    //Configure jasypt encryptor
    PooledPBEStringEncryptor strongEncryptor = new PooledPBEStringEncryptor();
    strongEncryptor.setAlgorithm("PBEWITHMD5ANDDES");
    strongEncryptor.setPassword("jasypt");
    strongEncryptor.setPoolSize(2);

    //Register it with hibernate
    HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry registry = HibernatePBEEncryptorRegistry.getInstance();
    registry.registerPBEStringEncryptor("strongHibernateStringEncryptor", strongEncryptor);

    //Get an entity manager factory
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("helloworld");

    //Get an entity manager
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
    tx.begin();

    //Create an employee
    Employee employee = new Employee();
    employee.setName("Vaibhav");
    employee.setSsn("1234567");
    em.persist(employee);

    tx.commit();

    EntityTransaction newtx = em.getTransaction();
    newtx.begin();

    //Search an employee with ssn
    Query queryObject1 = em.createNamedQuery("employee.getEmployeeBySSN");
    queryObject1.setParameter("ssn", "1234567");

    //No results here
    List employees1 = queryObject1.getResultList();

    newtx.commit();
    em.close();

}
```

I get no result in `employees1` list. However when I run the following named query, I'm able to see decrypted ssn in the employee object.

```
Query queryObject = em.createNamedQuery("employee.getEmployeeByName");
queryObject.setParameter("name", "Vaibhav");
List employees = queryObject.getResultList();
Employee employee1 = (Employee)employees.get(0);
```

I am unable to understand is there a bug in my code or is it how hibernate is supposed to work. 
In the documentation [Integrating Jasypt with Hibernate 3.x or 4.x](http://www.jasypt.org/hibernate.html), it is written that:

> But encryption sets a limitation on your Hibernate usage: security
>   standards establish that two different encryption operations on the
>   same data should not return the same value (due to the use of a random
>   salt). Because of this, none of the fields that are set to be
>   encrypted when persisted can be a part of a WHERE clause in your
>   search queries for the entity they belong to.

So it means that one cannot perform search operations on an encrypted field.

Answer (score 1):

I was using a random salt generator. After adding a zero salt generator, I was able to solve the issue:

```
strongEncryptor.setSaltGenerator(new ZeroSaltGenerator());
```